# Média pelo intervalo de linhas

Tags: r

Estou trabalhando no `R` apenas com 1 coluna, ela tem 3651 linhas e preciso fazer várias médias ao longo da coluna.

Preciso da média a cada 5 linhas. Estou trabalhando com dados de pressão atmosférica. e eles estão divididos em 1 em 1 minuto. Preciso da média de 5 para trabalhar com outra tabela onde os dados estão de 5 em 5.

```
set.seed(7863)
n <- 3651
```

Comment: A média de 5 em 5 observações é X_1 até X_5, X_2 até X_6, X_3 até X_7 e assim por diante ou X_1 até X_5, X_6 até X_10, X_11 até X_15 e por aí vai?

Comment: Seria essa opção:  X_1 até X_5, X_6 até X_10, X_11 até X_15 e por ai vai...

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de  `dput(head(dados, 20))`? É que se são dados em que entra uma variável tempo (em minutos) a resposta que eu dei pode mudar muito. Nota: `dados` é o nome da base, por exemplo de um data.frame.

Answer (score 1):

A função seguinte calcula médias

1. **`tipo = "segmentos"`** `m`. No caso da pergunta tem-se `m = 5`, isto é , as médias dos elementos 1-5 são calculadas, depois de 6-10, 11-15, etc.
2. **`tipo = "movel"`**. As médias dos elementos de 1-5 são calculadas, depois de 2-6, 3-7, etc. Este tipo de médias utiliza o pacote `zoo`.

O exemplo testa a função com um vetor, não com uma coluna de um dataframe.

```
mediaKamila <- function(x, m = 5, tipo = "segmentos", na.rm = TRUE, ...){
  n <- length(x)
  if(tipo == "movel"){
    zoo::rollmeanr(x, k = m, ...)
  }else{
    f <- c(1L, rep(0, m - 1))
    f <- cumsum(rep(f, ceiling(n / m), length.out = n))
    ave(x, f, FUN = mean, na.rm = na.rm)
  }
}

y <- 1:31
mediaKamila(y)
mediaKamila(y, tipo = "movel")
zoo::rollmeanr(1:31, 5)
```